# do i need to install sqlserver in another computer to access the database

Tags: sql-server, database

I created a database using microsoft sqlserver and an application that use the database. The application would be deployed on the client's computer as well as the database.

Do i need to install microsoft sqlserver on my client's computer in order to the database to work?

Comment: what you use for devloppement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you have just to configure your database to accept connection from other computer, and set the connection string for your server and databse

**more explanation :**

If I understand your edit, you want to Know if you have to install SqlServer in the Client Machine to run your application;

if this is your real question then yes, the sql server is relational database management system (an engine to manupulate your data base)

and in this case you have to update your string connexion related to the new sqlserver engine name and the path to this engine

Comment: On top, depending on the tehnology you use for programming, client libraries will already (likely) be installed already.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion i should have stated that the database would be transferred to my client's computer